# cups: connection timed out

Tags: centos, iptables, cups, output

I'm showing connection timed out in the `/var/log/cups/error_log`.

```
D [29/Oct/2015:17:43:32 -0400] cupsdSetBusyState: Printing jobs
D [29/Oct/2015:17:44:04 -0400] [Job 11441] Connection error: Connection timed out
```

I find that if I change the default OUTPUT policy to ACCEPT, cups processes my print jobs without a hitch.

Here is my iptables config (showing policy DROP)

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 4 packets, 262 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
61345   14M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
   60  3600 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443,636 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    1    76 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:123 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
   10   600 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    4   240 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
  265 15900 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 1433 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
   26  1662 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:445 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:139 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
 6143 2445K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:514 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

I'm allowing outbound traffic on port 631 (upd and tcp).

If I relax OUTPUT to ACCEPT, the print queue processes normally, but I am not showing any outbound traffic on port 631.

Here's the relevant section from `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`:

```
# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
Listen localhost:631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
```

This configuration worked until yesterday when I moved the printer to a new VLAN (from 2.2.2.2 to 3.3.3.3).  I can ping the printer OK with the firewall up.

What could be going on with my iptables config to prevent print jobs from being sent to the printer?